# Forward SIP request between two Kamailio servers

Tags: kamailio

I have a simulation setup of 4 VMs in Virtual Box - two UAs and two Kamailio servers. The first UA will register to KAM1, and the second UA will regsiter to KAM2. See the Figure below.

```
UA1<--->KAM1<---->KAM2<---->UA2
int1    int1      int3      int3
        int2      int2
```

I would like KAM1 to forward all SIP requests destined to int3 via KAM2 and vice versa. I am aware of the routing logic in 'kamailio.cfg', but i find rather excessive. Pseudo code of what i'm trying to achieve:

```
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {
             if(dst_ip == int3)
                 set_next_kamailio_server(KAM2)
    }
```

Or:

```
        if (is_method("INVITE")) {
             if(callee is unkown)
                 ask_kamailio_server(KAM2)
    }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Module is named [DMQ](https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.1.x/modules/dmq.html)/[USRLOC DMQ](https://kamailio.org/docs/modules/5.1.x/modules/dmq_usrloc.html) that can share information between nodes. maybe it can help you.
in addition you can send it with just edit Request Uri like below.

```
$ru="sip:"+$rU+"@"+KAM2ip 

t_relay()
```